# Интеграла два, а граница одна

Tags: математика

Есть задание вычислить интеграл, но область интегрирования задана как-то странно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли это понимать как систему, где `x > 1` и `y > 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как элементы *dxdy* написаны вместе ( НЕ между интегральными знаками ) означает, что постановщик задачи не видит разницу какую переменную засунуть раньше. Следовательно, граница вычислений симметрична относительно *x* и *y*.

Comment: то есть я правильно понял, что условие и для `x` и для `y` будет `> 0`?

Comment: обе границы будут с единицы на бесконечность